# Paypal IPN expiration

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

As I receive an IPN from PayPal, I would not like to process it immediately, but, instead, queue the message and then process it with a scheduler.

Therefore, there's a point that worries me - if I queue a message and only process it (including the '_notify-validate' verification), let's say, 12 hours later, will I be able to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't schedule a delay with PayPal for when we send out the IPN post and if you don't reply back to PayPal within a few seconds we'll reattempt to send the post later.

It is possible to not reply to, like, the first six IPN posts for a payment but doing that will eventually start to trigger an e-mail telling you that the posts are not being replied to right away. It may possibly lead to IPN being disabled on your account.